# Prefixes for C/C++ data members / objects

Tags: pointers, naming-conventions, prefix

I've been getting more and more involved in **C**/C++ programming lately and have noticed a trend in the way people name datatypes in their code.

I always see prefixes such as p, m, ui, etc.

For example: mPlayerNames, pData, uiNumResets

I think I get it, but just to confirm: Do these prefixes indicate the data type? i.e.:
mData -> Matrix (array) of Data
pData -> pointer to Data
uiData -> unsigned int Data
etc...

Is this correct?

Comment: Hungarian notation tends to be used in naming variables rather than types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m - member of a class
p - pointer
ui - unsigned int
lpsz - long pointer string zero terminated (whew!)
```

I personally only use the 'm' and the 'p'.  The rest is just zany in my view.  It makes the code so darn hard to decipher.

I did maintenance work on this guy's code who used semi-Hungarian notation type id prefixes on every variable, function, and other identifier in the code.  He used $ signs liberally to separate words.  It was hard to keep the murderous rage in check.

Comment: Is it really really popular to use this?

Comment: I'd say it is common but losing popularity.  Modern editing environments mitigate the need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally known as [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

There's nothing ironclad about the prefixes - they may vary among languages and platforms and programming shops.

And yes, your interpretations are probably correct - p and ui are common, and you'd have to check to see that m really is referring to Matrix in your environment, although it may refer to a class member.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are in a way correct

This link provides you more details on the Hungarian notation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation